# Can I use Apache James as an SMTP API

Tags: smtp, james

My requirements are different than others. I need to expose an SMTP interface to a customer, but I will need to use a different MTA to actually send messages. I will need to capture the message submitted by SMTP and do a considerable processing of that message, including trips to a database before it is sent out.

Can I use a combination of Apache James + Mailet in order to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for sure !

Your customer can send email to James, which will do the processing, and when you want, transfer it to your mta.

James strength comes from the fact you can define mail processing via XML, that there is a lot of building blocks (mailet/matchers) you can reuse, and that you can embedded custom code.

Cheers,